# Using unary or server streaming to return slice from grpc server to client

Tags: go, grpc

The following code is a simple Golang gRPC Server that currently uses unary API. In my Service (GetUsers), it is returning a type `*[]User` which is different from the type in the GetUsersResponse that is defined in my protobuf `*pb.GetUsersResponse`. Since they have different types, I ran a for loop to transfer the data from `*[]User` to `*pb.GetUsersResponse`, it's kinda like a hacky way to perform type casting with an additional for loop. In my client grpc code (also shown below), I am performing another for loop to send JSON response back to the frontend. Is there any way to avoid this? Should I use grpc unary or server-side streaming for this? Since this is a double for loop, server side streaming seems to reduce this to a single for loop.

```golang
func (s *usersGRPCServer) GetUsers(ctx context.Context, empty *empty.Empty) (*pb.GetUsersResponse, error) {
    users, err := s.service.GetUsers()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, status.Error(codes.Internal, "Internal Server Error")
    }

    // Convert []*User to []*pb.User directly
    var pbUsers []*pb.User
    for _, user := range *users {
        pbUsers = append(pbUsers, &pb.User{
            FirstName: user.FirstName,
            LastName:  user.LastName,
            Username:  user.Username,
            Email:     user.Email,
            Active:    int64(user.Active),
            Admin:     int64(user.Admin),
        })
    }

    return &pb.GetUsersResponse{
        Users: pbUsers,
    }, nil
}
```

```golang
// client grpc
func (app *application) grpcGetUsersHandler(urlString string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        grpcClient, _, err := newUsersGRPCClient(urlString)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"status": http.StatusInternalServerError, "message": "Internal Server Error"})
        }

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
        defer cancel()

        resp, err := grpcClient.GetUsers(ctx, &empty.Empty{})
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"status": http.StatusInternalServerError, "message": "Internal Server Error"})
            return
        }

        var usersData []map[string]interface{}
        for _, user := range resp.Users {
            userData := map[string]interface{}{
                "first_name": user.FirstName,
                "last_name":  user.LastName,
                "username":   user.Username,
                "email":      user.Email,
                "active":     user.Active,
                "admin":      user.Admin,
            }
            usersData = append(usersData, userData)
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusOK,
            "users":  usersData,
        })
    }
}
```

This is my .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "./proto";

 import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service UserService {
    rpc GetUsers(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (GetUsersResponse);
}

message User {
    string first_name = 1;
    string last_name = 2;
    string username = 3;
    string email = 4;
    int64 active = 5;
    int64 admin = 6;
}

message GetUsersResponse {
    repeated User users = 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a full view about your project, but f you're just using **one** grpc service and providing it with gin, just use `grpc-gateway` go package instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well-articulated question

Your approach and your code look good.

Although it's not explicitly documented as a [best practice](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/dos-donts/), it **is** good practice to separate your business logic types (e.g. `User`) from the Protobuf-generated types. Doing so provides you flexibility with the abstraction albeit at the expense of having to code|perform the mapping between types.

I'm unfamiliar with [Gin](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin) (!?) but there's a possible alternative to the code that converts the `proto.Message` to JSON using [`protojson`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson):

```golang
b, err := protojson.MarshalOptions{
    UseProtoNames: true,
}.Marshal(resp)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to JSON marshal: %v", err)
}

// Ship the JSON to Gin here
log.Printf("Response:\n%s",string(b))
```

In your case, your Protobuf name e.g. `last_name` matches your JSON field names. By default, `protojson` will lowerCamelCase the Go name (`LastName`) as `lastName`. The solution is to use [`MarshalOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson#MarshalOptions) and `UseProtoNames`.

I don't know whether switching between unary and streaming methods would simplify your type conversions.

I suspect you should not choose to use streaming because of a possible benefit on type conversion; rather you would consider streaming (and it's additional complexity) when, as in this case, your client and your server (and its backend) most naturally `GetUsers` as a stream of `User` messages rather than in discrete chunks.

Comment: Thanks! This is the perfect answer for my use case. For now, I only need to run the for loop on the grpc server side. I also performed an additional `json.Unmarshal(b, &responseData)` where responseData is `var responseData map[string]interface{}` to make the format nicer.